# openlayer begineer

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, epsg

i am beginner with open-layer i feel some difficulty in understand what is this piece of code mean 
    var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-1.788, 53.571).transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") // to Spherical Mercator
          );

here LonLat mean is it Longitude and Latitude? and what does EPSG:4326 & EPSG:900913 mean 
in some where i found EPSG stands for European Petroleum Survey Group, and dono what does those values after EPSG mean, could any one help in understanding

Answer (score 0):

As the code suggests, it's a projection.  Direct from wikipedia: [EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/).

And yes, a [LonLat](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/LonLat-js.html) object represents a longitude/latitude pair.